# Is there any plugin for Lightroom that enables face recognition?

Tags: lightroom, face-detection

Is there any plugin for Lightroom that enables face recognition (i.e. show me all photos where someone appears, and tell me which new ones you think the person is)? I've considered switching to Aperture just because of this feature.

Is Adobe considering that for a future release?

Comment: Are you interested in just face detection (show where the faces are in the photo) or in face recognition, where photos are tagged based on automatic identification of people?

Comment: And if the answer to this question is a) nothing exists now and b) no one knows about Adobe's future plans, is that a satisfying answer?

Comment: I have tried Windows Live Photo Gallery (v15.4.3555.308) and could not get it to work with Lightroom 3.4. For Raw files, it must be keeping the data in the database, as I cannot find it in the file. For JPG files, it adds a People value, but LR does not see it.
I've also tried Picasa before, but gave up when it locked up part way through 28,000 images. Hopefully someone will come up with a solution that works for LR.

Answer (score 7):

Lightroom 6 (the perpetual license version) and Lightroom CC (the subscription-based version) now offer a built-in [face recognition feature](https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom/help/face-recognition.html). It [doesn't work perfectly](https://youtu.be/WvT8vWlciD0?t=3m38s) yet, though.

Comment: Lightroom may or may not work, but it is painfully slow.  I imported a simple 25,000 pictures, and I thought it wasn't working.  16 core CPU and high end everything.  Also it barely use 6% of my CPU hahaha.  The program freezes a lot during import, and it even crashed out.  Picasa is literally a 1000x faster, 3-5 hours starting from scratch.

Answer (score 6):

You can also [use Windows Live Photo Gallery to add face tags](http://explore.live.com/windows-live-photo-gallery-face-facial-recognition-using?os=other) to the photos. It will be added as metadata properly and if you don't do anything else then you won't lose any of your other tagging done through LR.

Windows Live Photo Gallery seems to be more metadata friendly than Picasa. Or at least more predictable in what it does (not to mention I prefer the editing wizards a bit and find myself using them over LR sometimes).

Comment: As the questioner says they're considering Aperture it means they're using a Mac, so this won't be a solution for them.

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing that exist within Lightroom, though a lot of people are requesting it.

However, you can use Picasa to do the face recognition and tagging: see [here](http://creativetechs.com/tipsblog/add-face-recognition-to-lightroom-with-picasa/) and [here](http://regex.info/blog/lightroom-goodies/picasa-face-import).

Comment: Just a note for anyone that doesn't pay a lot of attention to the comments on articles, there's a pretty huge caveat in the comments for that first article... ending with the authors basically admitting that it won't work for the vast majority of folks as they wrote it up. Thankfully Jeffrey's plugin (second link) solves that. :)

Comment: It is certainly a workaround. Thanks for sharing. I hope someone knows of anything that does not have any external dependencies.