# Is there a people/face recognition filter for Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom, face-detection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any plugin for Lightroom that enables face recognition?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9968/is-there-any-plugin-for-lightroom-that-enables-face-recognition)

Is there a filter that recognises people for Lightroom? It would be useful for a first level filtering process, as I pick through my photos. I know there is something available on Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't anything like that.

You may use [Picasa for face-detection tagging](http://creativetechs.com/tipsblog/add-face-recognition-to-lightroom-with-picasa/), but that's pretty much all. There's been a [topic on adobe forums](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4625647) about including Face Detection, but nothing came out of it.

Comment: Also Windows Live Photo Gallery and the Apple Faces systems offer machine learning based face detection.